# localhost and http:// in php

Tags: php

I'm new in php

Normally we run our project in php like localhost/projectname

Now i want to run our project by simply type our project name on browser - projectname or http://projectname

so what is the setting for this.

ThankI

Comment: map your `projectname` to `localhost` in your `hosts` file. I am curious, why would you want to do that?

Comment: What webserver are you running? If you are running apache on linux, then you need to add the line "projectname  127.0.0.1" to /etc/hosts file and create a virtualhost. For that you will have to add a file "projectname" to /etc/apache2/sites-available. Google for what needs to be in the file. Then run this following command "a2ensite projectname" and reload apache.

Comment: It is not php related. To acheive what you need you will have to make changes in your web server and system `hosts` file

Answer (score 1):

This has very little to do with PHP - it has everything to do with what your browser does when you enter a URL. It will try to find a *host* called `projectname`... so unless you add host entries for each of your project names and map them all to 127.0.0.1 *and* perform some sort of rerouting in the server to detect which project to map to based on the Host header in the HTTP request, you're going to have problems.

Do you really have so many projects going on at a time that you can't just use bookmarks for this?

EDIT: Okay, so you're *actually* running on port 8080. Three options:

- Disable IIS unless you actually need it, and run PHP on port 80, then follow the steps above
- Follow the steps above and then just use a URL of http://projectname:8080
- Add the host entries for each project but then configure IIS itself to perform a redirect from http://projectname to http://localhost/projectname (which means you wouldn't need to reconfigure PHP)

Personally I still think it's a bit of a waste of time...

Comment: hi,

simple localhost using 127.0.0.1 so it call project name 
but in my system 127.0.0.1 used by Microsoft TCP/IP so i'm using 127.0.0.1:8080 port.
It is possible to do with 127.0.0.1:8080
Thanks

Comment: @kanchan: By "Microsoft TCP/IP" I assume you mean "IIS"? (TCP/IP is a protocol, not a program.) So when in your question you state that you use "localhost/projectname" you actually mean "localhost:8080/projectname"? It's helpful to be careful when you write your question. Editing...

Comment: I disabled my IIS using control panel now when i'm typeing localhost it's showing 404 not fount.

Comment: @kanchan: Well you've got to tell PHP to run on port 80 as well, of course... and then until you've done anything else, you'd still need http://localhost/projectname

Answer (score 0):

If you are using win try this. 
Use notepad or notepad++ etc.
Open up the host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) and add the following:

127.0.0.1 {url you specified for the binding} in your case the name of your project.

Comment: hi, simple localhost using 127.0.0.1 so it call project name but in my system 127.0.0.1 used by Microsoft TCP/IP so i'm using 127.0.0.1:8080 port. It is possible to do with 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Is this a question ?I don't understand you please explain!

Comment: In my system i'm running my project using localhost:8080/project name now i want to run it by simple type my project name on browser,
simple question.

Comment: Then  i have answer your question  i think.

Answer (score 0):

in easy steps:

1. open the the with the name `hosts` if you are using windows OS then follow the URL `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc` in windows
2. just type your project name after the `127.0.0.1       localhost` like
   `127.0.0.1       projectname.com`

and after that map the location of your folder in the `httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: hi, simple localhost using 127.0.0.1 so it call project name but in my system 127.0.0.1 used by Microsoft TCP/IP so i'm using 127.0.0.1:8080 port. It is possible to do with 127.0.0.1:8080